# Matplotlib() isn't showing graph, instead displaying Restart message

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, backend, spyder

I'm using Python 2.7.11 on Windows 8.1 with 64 bit processor.I was trying out an example from youtube video tutorials on Forex and Stock analysis by Sentdex. Whenever I run the following code:

```
import matplotlib  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker  
import matplotlib.dates as mdates  
import numpy as np  
import sys  
import pylab   
sys.path.insert(0,"F:\\Study Material\\CML\\Resources\\Data Science\\ \
                MACHINE LEARNING\\Hands-on\\Sentdex\\GBPUSD")
def graphRawFx():     
   date,bid,ask = np.loadtxt('GBPUSD1d.txt', unpack = True, \   
                              delimiter = ',',\
                              converters = {0:mdates.strpdate2num\
                                            ('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')})
    fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10,7))
    ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((40,40), (0,0), rowspan = 40, colspan = 40)
    ax1.plot(date,bid)
    ax1.plot(date,ask)
    ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show()
```

The following message is displayed: 
[Message displayed on Python Shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNGk8.jpg)

The plot is not being displayed for this particular code (whereas it displays plot for a simple program). I've tried changing the backend, tried using 'pylab' but same message is displayed every time. I've tried running the same code on Anaconda (Spyder) as well but the following message is displayed:
    [Spyder (Python 2.7)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yGYT.jpg)

Comment: how you run this code?